# How to check the health of a GPU

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I have a GTX 1080Ti which I have been using as my personal deep learning card for about 3,5 years. Lately, I'm getting a lot of obscure CUDA errors. Training and inference code that was running fine before, is now throwing errors after running for a few minutes (or my pc shuts down).

It's usually a version of:

```
CUDA: unspecified launch failure
```

I'm starting to suspect that it's a hardware problem with my GPU. I was wondering if there are ways to confirm this? (NOTE: apart from these errors the GPU seems fine - no visual artifacts on my monitor or anything like that.)

For example I have tried:

- https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/cuda_memtest (test didn't show any fault with my GPU)

Are there any other ways?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: gpuburn has helped for me

Answer (score 0):

> Training and inference code that was running fine before, is now throwing errors after running for a few minutes

Sounds like the card could be failing.

---

> (or my pc shuts down)

Sounds like the power supply could be failing

---

I would start by replacing the cheaper option, the power supply.

It's possible that a faulty power supply is causing GPU faults.